# How to set docker-machine env for fabric local() commands

Tags: python, docker, fabric, docker-machine

I'm trying to run commands against a docker-machine cloud provider, and so I need to take the contents of the command `docker-machine env digitalocean` which is typically as follows:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://1.2.3.4:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/danh/.docker/machine/machines/digitalocean"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="digitalocean"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval "$(docker-machine env digitalocean)"
```

and use the above as a shell prefix, such as:

```
print 'outside with:' + local('echo $DOCKER_HOST')
with prefix(local('docker-machine env digitalocean', capture=True)):
    print 'inside with:' + local('echo $DOCKER_HOST')
with prefix('DOCKER_HOST="tcp://1.2.3.4:2376"'):
    print 'inside with (manual):' + local('echo $DOCKER_HOST')
```

However this instead returns:

```
outside with:tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
inside with:
inside with (manual):tcp://1.2.3.4:2376
```

The only way I can see to get past this is to rip apart the result of `local('docker-machine env digitalocean')` manually. Surely there is a more fabric-esque way however?

Comment: It would appear that the *inside with* local ends up something like `export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1" echo $DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` which is not what you want. I doubt this will work. But have you tried to `eval` the `docker-machine` command to set the environment just like you normally would on the shell? My guess is that each `local` is in its own shell so this probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's the solution I've gone with so far, feels a bit hacky though:

```
def dm_env(machine):
    """
    Sets the environment to use a given docker machine.
    """
    _env = local('docker-machine env {}'.format(machine), capture=True)
    # Reorganize into a string that could be used with prefix().
    _env = re.sub(r'^#.*$', '', _env, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # Remove comments
    _env = re.sub(r'^export ', '', _env, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # Remove `export `
    _env = re.sub(r'\n', ' ', _env, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # Merge to a single line
    return _env

@task
def blah():
    print 'outside with: ' + local('echo $DOCKER_HOST')
    with prefix(dm_env('digitalocean')):
        print 'inside with: ' + local('echo $DOCKER_HOST')
```

Outputs:

```
outside with: tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
inside with: tcp://1.2.3.4:2376
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the required information is to use formatting templates for the output of the `docker-machine inspect` command, as also [shown in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/inspect/#examples).

Note that curly brackets in Python strings need to be escaped by doubling them, so you end up having **four** opening and closing brackets each time.

```
machine_name = dev
machine_ip = local("docker-machine inspect --format='{{{{.Driver.IPAddress}}}}' {0}".format(machine_name), capture=True)
machine_port = local("docker-machine inspect --format='{{{{.Driver.EnginePort}}}}' {0}".format(machine_name), capture=True)
machine_cert_path = local("docker-machine inspect --format='{{{{.HostOptions.AuthOptions.StorePath}}}}' {0}".format(machine), capture=True)
```

Now, you can use the [shell_env context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.shell_env) in order to temporarily point your Docker daemon to a remote machine by setting the according environment variables:

```
from fabric.api import shell_env
with shell_env(DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY='1',
               DOCKER_HOST='tcp://{0}:{1}'.format(machine_ip, machine_port),
               DOCKER_CERT_PATH=machine_cert_path,
               DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=machine_name):

    # will print containers on the remote machine
    local('docker ps -a')

# will print containers on your local machine 
# since environment switch is only valid within the context manager
local('docker ps -a')
```